# Is there a way to ask gcc to treat #include <> like #include ""?

Tags: c, gcc, header, include, c-preprocessor

Is there a compiler or preprocessor flag that will force gcc to treat `#include <x.h>` like it would `#include "x.h"`? I have a bunch of generated code that uses `#include <>` for files in the current directory, and gcc reports No such file or directory for these files. I'm looking for a workaround that doesn't involve editing the code.

EDIT: `-I.` doesn't do it. Let's say I have the following files:

foo/foo.h:

```
#include <foo2.h>
```

foo/foo2.h:

```
#define FOO 12345
```

xyz/xyz.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo/foo2.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("FOO is %d\n", FOO);
    return 0;
}
```

If, inside the `xyz` directory, I compile with `gcc -o xyz I.. xyz.c`, the compile fails:

```
In file included from xyz.c:2:
../foo/foo.h:1:18: error: foo2.h: No such file or directory
xyz.c: In function ‘main’:
xyz.c:6: error: ‘FOO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
xyz.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
xyz.c:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Adding `-I.` doesn't change anything.

But, if I change foo/foo.h to:

```
#include "foo2.h"
```

Then the compile works. I know I could add `-I../foo` to my command line, but I was looking for a more generic way to treat `#include <>` as `#include ""`. Does one exist?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can pass the switch `-I .` to the compiler to add the current directory to the include search path.

Answer (score 3):

The -I- option might help you.  From gcc's man page:

```
   -I- Split the include path.  Any directories specified with -I options
       before -I- are searched only for headers requested with
       "#include "file""; they are not searched for "#include <file>".  If
       additional directories are specified with -I options after the -I-,
       those directories are searched for all #include directives.
```